# Python While loop not ending when variable changes

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, while-loop

The while loop does not stop when var[5] changes from "" to "left" or "right"

```
#Variable Input
name = input("Enter your name: ")
place = input("Enter where you live: ")
sex = input("Are you a boy (Y/N): ")
scaryanimal = input("Enter the type of animal that you are most scared of: ")
happyanimal = input("Enter your favourite type of animal: ")
var=[name,place,sex,scaryanimal,happyanimal,""]

#Main story

#Other code goes here

#Offending While loop

while var[5].lower() != "left" or var[5].lower() != "right": 
        var[5] = input("Did he go left or right: ")
        print(var[5])
```

Comment: I don't see where you're changing `var[5]`. If you think `vari = input(...)` changes the content of `var`, you may be misunderstanding the syntax for list assignment.

Comment: Oops, just realised that I forgot to replace vari with var[5], I changed var[5] to a variable to check if it was the array that was faulty. :-(

Comment: was your original code "correct" with `var[5]` instead of `vari`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read you say that your variable is changing, but where?

Two things: you've got to change the variable you're checking AND you have to change that condition test, that while loop condition is `True` when the variable `var[5]` is different than 'left' or different that 'right' (if it's "left", then it's different than 'right' and so the loop will continue)

So...

```
while var[5].lower() != "left" and var[5].lower() != "right": 
    var[5] = input("Did he go left or right: ")
    print(var[5])
```